# If $ A^2=0$ , prove that $A$ doesn't neccesarily have a row of zeros

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Question**

$A^2 \in M_{n \times n} (F), A^2=0, n\ge 3$.
Prove that it's not true that A necessarily has a row of zeros.

**Thoughts**
We thought that the matrix must be nilpotent, but therefore it's main diagonal is 0s (and must mean that there's a line of zeros). I'd love to see a method of finding the counterexample for this one.
Thanx

Comment: but if A is nilpotent then what we're saying is true, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry: I misread, so my example is nonsense.

Comment: Note that a nonzero square matrix is always similar to a matrix where every row is nonzero: it suffices to take a basis containing no vector of $\ker A^T$. This can be done randomly if you want with a solid probability of success: that's Seirios approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take an easy example, like $A= \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0&0 \end{matrix} \right)$ or $A= \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1&0 \end{matrix} \right)$. Then, let $A_P=PAP^{-1}$ where $P \in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$. Of course, $A_P^2=0$ and if you choose correctly $P$, $A_P$ does not contain a row of zeros.

Randomly, my fist attempt was $P= \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1&1 \end{matrix} \right)$ and $A_P= \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1&-1 \end{matrix} \right)$.

In dimension three, with $A= \left( \begin{matrix} 0&0&1 \\ 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0 \end{matrix} \right)$ and $P= \left( \begin{matrix} 1&2&3 \\ 2&3&1 \\ 3&1&2 \end{matrix} \right)$ we get the conterexample: $$A_P= \frac{1}{18} \left( \begin{matrix} 7&-5&1 \\ 14&-10&2 \\ 21&-15&3 \end{matrix} \right)$$

Comment: I figured that was the case: it was easy to overlook!

Answer (score 10):

It's not even true in 2 dimensions; just make a matrix whose rows and columns are orthogonal. For example, the matrix with 1 1 on top and -1 -1 on bottom. Try generalizing this.